# Finding integer solution to a quadratic equation in two unknowns

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> We have an equation:
>   $$m^2 = n^2 + m + n + 2018.$$
>   Find all integer pairs $(m,n)$ satisfying this equation.

Comment: Well, if $(m,n)$ is a solutions, integer or not, what is the formula for $m$ in terms of $n$ (or vice versa)?  Now which values can to be integers.

Answer (score 11):

Hint $$ (m+n)(m-n)= (m+n)+2018$$

so $$ (m+n)(m-n-1)= 2018$$

Answer (score 4):

**Guide**: Write $m=n+k$ for some integer $k$, then $$n^2+2nk+k^2= n^2+2n+k+2018$$

so $$ n={-k^2+k+2018\over 2(k-1)}=-{k\over 2}+{1009\over k-1}$$

If $k$ is odd then there is no solution, so $k= 2s$ so $$2s-1\mid 1009$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Simpler start: separating variables to either side gives:
$$m^2-m=n^2+n+2018$$
which then factors roughly for the variables as:
$$m(m-1)=n(n+1)+2018$$

which since both pairs(m,m-1) and (n,n+1) are consecutive integers, you can divide both sides by two giving:

$$\frac{m(m-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1009$$

But, $\frac{y(y+1)}{2}$ is the form of the y-th triangular number, so the solutions are such that 1009 is the difference of two triangular numbers $T_{\vert m-1 \vert}$ and $T_{\vert n \vert}$ . Solve for n, and m-1 .